# iTunes store not loading

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I have had this problem for about one month with my itunes store. I get a blank white screen. Tried upgrading to latest version (11.0.4 now) but nothing seems to be working.

Here's the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Are you able to access the iTunes store through a web browser? i.e. try this link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731

Comment: Yes tubedogg, itunes links are loading in browser. Thanks

Comment: Anyone knows why this happens? I still haven't figured out a solution to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get it working, I installed all my updates one at a time (instead of all at once since I was having a problem with updates installation).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Snow Leopard? Update the Safari then it will show.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1569